# Cannot read property 'commitment_id' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have a page that opens on such a routing `commitments/:id`.
And I want to display the dates of reports belonging to this particular page, by id. But I get an  message that it is impossible to read the property "commitment_id":

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'commitment_id' of undefined
>
> at eval (commitment.component.ts:88)
>
> at Array.filter ()
>
> at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (commitment.component.ts:87)
>
> at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:239)
>
> at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:186)
>
> at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:127)
>
> at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)
>
> at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:127)
>
> at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)
>
> at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)

ts:

```
    commitments: Array<Commitment>;
    selectedCommitment = null;
    reportingDates: Array<ReportingDate>;
    filteredReportingDates = [];
    id: number;
    routeId: any;
    public errorMsg;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.routeId = this.route.params.subscribe(
          params => {
            this.id = +params['id'];
          }
        )
        let commitmentRequest = this.route.params
          .flatMap((params: Params) =>
            this.servCommitment.getCommitment(+params['id' ]));
        commitmentRequest.subscribe(response => this.commitment = response.json(), error => this.errorMsg = error);

    }

  @Input() commitment: Commitment;

    onSelectedReportingDate(commitmentId) {
        this.selectedCommitment = this.commitments.find(
          (el) => {
            return el.commitment_id === commitmentId
          }
        );
    
        this.servReportingDate.getReportingDates().subscribe(
          reportingDate => {
            this.reportingDates = reportingDate;
            this.filteredReportingDates = this.reportingDates.filter(
              (reportingDate) => reportingDate.l_commitments_id === this.selectedCommitment.commitment_id
            );
          }
        );
    }
```

html:

```
<div *ngIf="commitment">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-simple" (click)="onSelectedReportingDate(commitment.commitment_id)">Test</button>
  <div *ngIf="selectedLiability">
   <div *ngFor="let reportingDate of filteredReportingDates">
        {{ reportingDate.reportingdate_plan }}
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

line 87-88-89:

```
  this.filteredReportingDates = this.reportingDates.filter(
    (reportingDate) => reportingDate.l_commitments_id === this.selectedCommitment.commitment_id
  );
```

Comment: What is the code present at line no 88 `commitment.component.ts:88`. Highlight that also

Comment: yes, the code provided is fine, error must be in `commitment.component.ts:88`

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT added to the question

Comment: @user10471254 issue might be after `this.selectedCommitment = this.commitments.find(` line. can you do `console.log(this.selectedCommitment)` after find? and check the console

Comment: I see nowhere that you actually set any value for `this.commitments`, so when trying to do a `find` for that array, `selectedCommitment` would be `undefined` there and when you are on line 88 trying to read the `commitment_id` of `selectedCommitment` it's `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `commitment_id` exist in the variable

```
(reportingDate) => this.selectedCommitment && (reportingDate.l_commitments_id === this.selectedCommitment.commitment_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

**You need only null or undefined check on the variable this.selectedCommitment as its undefined.**

A small modification of @Sachila Ranawaka code:

```
(reportingDate) => this.selectedCommitment && (reportingDate.l_commitments_id === this.selectedCommitment.commitment_id)
```

Comment: this will throw an error if `commitment_id` not exist on `selectedCommitment ` object

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka no it will not throw error , the condition will get false in that case, you can check that

Comment: ohh yes. my mistake. Updated it

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka Thanks alot bro